# Jest expo can't find transform attributes - missing assetFileTransformer.js file

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

I've written some tests with Jest in my React Native expo app. When I run the tests they pass but I also always get this notification:

```
Expected react-native/jest-preset to define transform[^.+\.(bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|mp4|png|psd|svg|webp)$]
react-native/jest-preset contained different transformIgnorePatterns than expected
```

this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "verbose": true,
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.6.2",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-font": "^8.1.1",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "11.0.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "readme-md-generator": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "jest-expo": "^38.0.2",
    "react-native-testing-library": "^2.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is the jest.preset file:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 *
 * @format
 */

'use strict';

module.exports = {
  haste: {
    defaultPlatform: 'ios',
    platforms: ['android', 'ios', 'native'],
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|ts|tsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|mp4|png|psd|svg|webp)$': require.resolve(
      './jest/assetFileTransformer.js',
    ),
  },  
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native-community)',
  ],
  setupFiles: [require.resolve('./jest/setup.js')],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

As far as I can tell the from the jest preset file the right transform attributes should be in a assetFileTransformer.js file. I have this file and it seems to be in the right place but it can't be found. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: *This is the jest.preset file* - which one? The config clearly says that the preset is`"preset": "jest-expo"`.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have made this more clear. this was a confusing part of the Expo documentation (https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/), because nowhere is said in which file the configuration has to go. I prefer it to be in the package.json file but a preset files is automatically made in the node_modules folder with some settings. I removed the configuration one at a time from both files but that didn't solve anything. I also tried  the <rootDir> suggestion from the Jest documentation (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulepathignorepatterns-arraystring) to no avail.